# How to print the elements of 2D matrix as rectangular shape by the input given by user

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've come across this question in one of the assessments in our college. None of my friends were able to help me out. I even checked all leading online platforms for my desired output criteria. But no use, so I wanted to post my question in Stack Overflow.

I request people who are watching this tag to help me out. Even though my assessment has been completed, I'm eagerly trying to solve this problem but I couldn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

     int a[4][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {5, 6, 7, 8},
                    {9, 10, 11, 12},
                    {13, 14, 15, 16}};

     int k, l, m, n, o, r;

     int temp[4][4] = {0};
     printf("Enter index of row & column: ");

     int p, q;
     scanf("%d %d", &p, &q);

     for (int i = p; i < 4; i++)
     {
          for (int j = q; j < 4; j++)
          {
               temp[i][j] = a[i][j];
               // initial given index number to left_most number
          }
          k = i + 1, l = 4 - q;

          for (k; k <= l; k++)
          {
               temp[k][l] = a[k][l];
               //rightmost element to bottom
          }
          m = k - 1, n = l - 1;

          for (n; n >= q; n--)
          {
               temp[m][n] = a[m][n];
               //bottomright to left elements upto the column index provided by user
          }
          o = m, r = q;

          for (o; o >= i + 1; o--)
          {
               temp[o][r] = a[o][r];
               //bottomleft to initial index element
          }
          break;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
          for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
          {

               //if the element is zero then priting a space else printing the number
               if (temp[i][j] == 0)
               {
                    printf(" ");
               }

               else
               {
                    printf("%d ", temp[i][j]);
               }
          }
          printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:
Enter index of row & column: 0 1

Sample Output:

```
2  3  4
6     8
10    12
14 15 16
```

My code only works for sample input and the following column.

So I need help on how to make my code work for any input given by user, it has to print the zero(0) shape out of it.

Comment: While this is valid C++, it is a much better fit for the C programming language. I left the C++ tag, but you might want to remove it. Visual Studio code and C++14 have absolutely no bearing on this question, so I removed their tags.

Comment: thankyou for that Sir.
I'm new to the stack overflow community. So I apologize for it

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like for other inputs? All we have to work from is the given code and by your own admission it doesn't work. This make it hard to determine what the code should do. For example, what should the output of, say 10, 3 be?

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty neat solution to this problem

```
  for (int r = 0; r < numrows; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < numcols; c++) {
          if (r >= p && c >= q && 
             (c == q || c == numcols - 1 || r == p || r == numrows - 1)){
             printf("%2d ",a[r][c]);
          }
          else {
             printf("  ");
          }
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
```

where `numrows = 4` and `numcols = 4`

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is no need to declare an auxiliary array if the task is just to output a sub-array of the original array.

A straightforward approach in C can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rectangle_pattern( size_t n, int a[][n], size_t row, size_t col )
{
    for ( size_t i = row; i < n; ++i )
    {
        if ( i == row || i == n - 1 )
        {
            for ( size_t j = col; j < n; j++ )
            {
                printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%2d", a[i][col] );
            if ( col != n - 1 ) printf( "%*d", ( int )( 3 * ( n - col - 1 ) ), a[i][n-1] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 4 };
    int a[N][N]= 
    { 
        {  1,  2,  3,  4 },
        {  5,  6,  7,  8 }, 
        {  9, 10, 11, 12 }, 
        { 13, 14, 15, 16 } 
    };

    size_t row = 0, col = 0;
    
    rectangle_pattern( N, a, row, col );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    row = 0, col = 1;
    
    rectangle_pattern( N, a, row, col );
    
    putchar( '\n' );

    row = 0, col = 2;
    
    rectangle_pattern( N, a, row, col );
    
    putchar( '\n' );

    row = 0, col = 3;
    
    rectangle_pattern( N, a, row, col );
    
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 1  2  3  4 
 5        8
 9       12
13 14 15 16 

 2  3  4 
 6     8
10    12
14 15 16 

 3  4 
 7  8
11 12
15 16 

 4 
 8
12
16
```

The function declaration uses a variable length array as a parameter. You can change the function declaration declaring the parameter as having an array with a fixed size.

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer was very useful.